# Request JSON Alamofire serialization failure with Swift

Tags: json, swift, http, alamofire

I have this content: https://pastebin.com/HVDC1G0F
I'm making an HTTP request with Alamofire to retrieve this content.
Here is my code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/Student/Grade/GetFinalGrades")
                .responseJSON(completionHandler: {
                    response in

                    print(response)

                })
```

But when I print the response I get this error:

```
    FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 198." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 198.}))
```

That's weird because the JSON file seems to be clean. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: `"iconCls": X.net.RM.getIcon("BulletWhite"),`: that doesn't look like valid JSON.

Comment: How can I bypass this?

Comment: Ask your service to send a real JSON? It's just hack if not (and not recommended). A hack: use reponseString (not JSON), search for `X.net.RM.getIcon("something")`, and replace it with `"something", convert it back to (NS)Data with and use yourself NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: How can i concert it back to NSData?

Comment: It seems to be a good idea

Comment: There are plenty of question about transforming `(NS)String` to `(NS)Data` on SO. In Objective-C, it's `dataUsingEncoding:`. There is a Swift equivalent.

Comment: By doing this I lose the JSON format of the file... How can I convert my data string into JSON?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145651/discussion-between-larme-and-greenpoison-onetv).